# How to solve object is not an instance of declaring class in Liferay

Tags: java, servlets, liferay

I am trying to deploy a book application which will display some book information and also allow user to add,remove,delete,upload/download etc.But while i am trying to deploy the application i am getting error of object is not an instance of delaring class .I don't know how to solve this erro please help i am posting my exception

```
14:13:12,567 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-1][PortletServlet:116]  javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:323)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:677)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:406)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1242)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:120)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:174)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:319)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy418.filterRenderURL(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.doCreateLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:692)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:773)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil$NoPACL.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:26)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:267)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:259)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:281)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:291)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:286)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.generateUrls(BookCatalogPortlet.java:436)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.showBooks(BookCatalogPortlet.java:214)
... 44 more
Apr 18, 2015 2:13:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet BookCatalog Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at   com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy418.filterRenderURL(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.doCreateLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:692)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:773)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil$NoPACL.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:26)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:267)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:259)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:281)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:291)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:286)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.generateUrls(BookCatalogPortlet.java:436)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.showBooks(BookCatalogPortlet.java:214)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:319)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:677)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:406)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1242)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:120)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:174)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

 14:13:12,583 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-1][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.doCreateLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:692)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:773)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl$LiferayPortletURLPrivilegedAction.run(PortletResponseImpl.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil$NoPACL.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:26)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:267)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:259)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:281)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:291)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletResponseImpl.createRenderURL(PortletResponseImpl.java:286)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.generateUrls(BookCatalogPortlet.java:436)
at com.msh.base.BookCatalogPortlet.showBooks(BookCatalogPortlet.java:214)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:319)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
 14:27:50,329 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:180] Entering showBooks method
 14:27:50,332 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:144] Size of the Database :4
 14:27:50,332 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:145] Current book count in catalog : 4
 14:27:50,333 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode edit
 14:27:50,333 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode help
 14:27:50,333 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode view
 14:27:50,333 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode about
 14:27:50,333 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode config
 14:27:50,334 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode edit_defaults
14:27:50,334 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode preview
14:27:50,334 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:506] Support portlet mode print
14:27:50,335 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:519] Support window state maximized
14:27:50,335 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:519] Support window state minimized
14:27:50,335 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:519] Support window state normal
14:27:50,336 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:519] Support window state exclusive
14:27:50,336 INFO  [BookCatalogPortlet:519] Support window state pop_up
14:27:50,341 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-3][PortletServlet:116]     javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:323)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
```

These are GenerateUrls() and showBooks() method

```
private void generateUrls(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
        throws PortletModeException, WindowStateException {
    // Render URL for Print hyperlink
    PortletURL printModeUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    if (request.isPortletModeAllowed(new PortletMode("print"))) {
        printModeUrl.setPortletMode(new PortletMode("print"));
    }
    if (request.isWindowStateAllowed(new WindowState("pop_up"))) {
        printModeUrl.setWindowState(new WindowState("pop_up"));
    }
    request.setAttribute("printModeUrl", printModeUrl);

    // Action URL for upload Toc action
    PortletURL uploadTocActionUrl = response.createActionURL();
    uploadTocActionUrl.setParameter("myaction", "uploadTocAction");
    uploadTocActionUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,
            "uploadTocAction");
    request.setAttribute("uploadTocActionUrl", uploadTocActionUrl);

    // Render URL for Full Screen hyperlink
    PortletURL fullScreenUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    fullScreenUrl.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
    request.setAttribute("fullScreenUrl", fullScreenUrl);

    // Render URL for Help hyperlink
    PortletURL helpUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    helpUrl.setPortletMode(PortletMode.HELP);
    request.setAttribute("helpUrl", helpUrl);

    // Render URL for Home hyperlink
    PortletURL homeUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    homeUrl.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
    request.setAttribute("homeUrl", homeUrl);

    // Render URL for Preferences hyperlink
    PortletURL prefUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    prefUrl.setPortletMode(PortletMode.EDIT);
    request.setAttribute("prefUrl", prefUrl);

    // Render URL for form submission for Adding book
    PortletURL addBookFormUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    addBookFormUrl.setParameter("myaction", "addBookForm");
    request.setAttribute("addBookFormUrl", addBookFormUrl);

    // Action URL for Add Book Action
    PortletURL addBookActionUrl = response.createActionURL();
    addBookActionUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,
            "addBookAction");
    request.setAttribute("addBookActionUrl", addBookActionUrl);

    // Action URL for resetting search
    PortletURL resetActionUrl = response.createActionURL();
    resetActionUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "resetAction");
    request.setAttribute("resetActionUrl", resetActionUrl);

    // Action URL for searching books
    PortletURL searchBookActionUrl = response.createActionURL();
    searchBookActionUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,
            "searchBookAction");
    request.setAttribute("searchBookActionUrl", searchBookActionUrl);

    // Render URL for Refresh Search Results link
    PortletURL refreshResultsUrl = response.createRenderURL();
    refreshResultsUrl.setParameter("myaction", "refreshResults");
    request.setAttribute("refreshResultsUrl", refreshResultsUrl);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RenderMode(name = "VIEW")
public void showBooks(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("Entering showBooks method");

    //--return if the content is still valid
    if(isMarkupValid(request, response)) {
        response.getCacheControl().setUseCachedContent(true);
        response.getCacheControl().setExpirationTime(100);
        return;
    } else {
        BookDataObject catalog = (BookDataObject) getPortletContext()
        .getAttribute("bookCatalog");
        int currentCountInDatastore = catalog.getBooks().size();
        // -- set the currentCountInDatabase as the etag value
        response.getCacheControl().setETag("" + currentCountInDatastore);
    }

    PortalContext context = request.getPortalContext();
    printSupportedPortletModes(context);
    printSupportedWindowStates(context);
    // --get user attributes user.name.given and user.name.family
    Map<String, Object> userAttributeMap = (Map<String, Object>) request
            .getAttribute(PortletRequest.USER_INFO);
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    if (userAttributeMap != null) {
        firstName = (String) userAttributeMap.get("user.name.given");
        lastName = (String) userAttributeMap.get("user.name.family");
        request.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
        request.setAttribute("lastName", lastName);
    }

    String portalInfo = context.getPortalInfo();
    request.setAttribute("portalInfo", portalInfo);

    // --generate all the URLs that will be used by the portlet
    generateUrls(request, response);

    String myaction = request.getParameter("myaction");
    if (myaction != null) {
        logger.info("myaction parameter is not null. Value is " + myaction);
        request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("myaction", myaction,
                PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
    } else {
        // -- if myaction is NULL then show the home page of Book
        // catalog
        // page
        request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("myaction", "showCatalog",
                PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
    }

    // -- send myaction as a request attribute to the BookServlet.
    request.setAttribute("myaction", request.getPortletSession()
            .getAttribute("myaction"));

    // --dynamically obtain the title for the portlet, based on myaction
    String titleKey = "portlet.title."
            + (String) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("myaction");
    response.setTitle(getResourceBundle(request.getLocale()).getString(
            titleKey));

    // --if the action is uploadTocForm then store the ISBN number of
    // the
    // --book for which the TOC is being uploaded. The upload action
    // will use the ISBN number to create file name -- refer home.jsp
    // page
    if (((String) request.getAttribute("myaction"))
            .equalsIgnoreCase("uploadTocForm")) {
        request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("isbnNumber",
                request.getParameter("isbnNumber"));
    }

    if (((String) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("myaction"))
            .equalsIgnoreCase("showSearchResults")) {
        request.setAttribute("matchingBooks", request.getPortletSession()
                .getAttribute("matchingBooks"));
    }

    // its important to encode URLs
    PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getPortletSession()
            .getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    response.encodeURL("/myservlet/bookServlet"));
    dispatcher.include(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Shall we guess what your code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your showBooks() or generateUrls() method you cast an object to another object or do something with an object that is illegal. If you could post the code in the two methods mentioned I could give you a better answer.

Comment: PortletURL printModeUrl = response.createRenderURL(); this line causing error but why it can not create renderURL

Answer (score 0):

As the problem lies deeper within the stacktrace, my guess is that you have some files on the classpath that better shouldn't be there, or are on there twice. Make sure that you have, for example, portlet.jar in the appserver's global classpath and not in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib`. Same goes for portal-impl.jar, that one should live within Liferay, but nowhere else - neither global nor your application.

Also, it might help to mark some line numbers. You have several appearances of response.createRenderURL in the code and it'd be good to know if the problem is in the first appearance or some time later.

Comment: the problem is not with the first renderUrl if i delete that then in the next URL i.e PortletURL uploadTocActionUrl = response.createActionURL(); i also get the same error line number 447

Comment: as you suggested i have removed all jars from my classpath and only the required jar specific to the application is there like commons.fileupload,commons.lang,jstl.1.2 there are requied jar as the as my applcation does upload and download of files but still having the same error in the same function